# convert gif to mp4 (gif2mp4)

Tags: video, conversion, ffmpeg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert an animated GIF to a YouTube friendly video format?](https://superuser.com/questions/5730/how-do-i-convert-an-animated-gif-to-a-youtube-friendly-video-format)

The question is pretty straight-forward:
How to convert animated gif file to mp4 video?

It might seem totally useless but it can come handy when trying to insert animations to a PDF presentation (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429/animation-in-pdf-presentations-without-adobe-reader) and to avoid uneccessary complications needed to get adobe reader working (http://abarry.org/the-complete-guide-to-embedded-videos-in-beamer-under-linux/).

Comment: Here are some one step solutions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40638/how-to-do-i-convert-an-animated-gif-to-an-mp4-or-mv4-on-the-command-line

Answer (score 8):

Step 1: Extract all frames from the input gif file (using imagemagick)

```
 convert INPUT.gif gif%05d.png
```

Step 2: Convert frames to video

```
 ffmpeg -r FRAMERATE -i gif%05d.png -y -an OUTPUT.mp4
```

Step 3 (optional): Delete all unnecessary temporal files

```
  rm gif*.png
```

Take care when deleting files.

Edit: In some versions of Ubuntu and Debian *ffmpeg* was replaced by *avconv* but the syntax remains same.

Comment: FYI, FFmpeg isn't obsolete, it's still there and actively maintained. `avconv` is merely the fork Ubuntu chose to bundle.